# Is there an easy way of running a program from a Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I only found `runtime.connectNative` and from what I read it is overly complex (it requires OS specific configuration of target executable, permissions for addond and other over-engineered things). I am looking for a trivial solution on a few lines like:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('pwd', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: which type of firefox addon? webExtensions? jpm extensions? overlay (XUL) extensions?

Comment: From what I gather no other type than webextensions will be supported in very near future, so webextensions.

Comment: just making sure :p so, is there any documented way of doing it? I don't think I've seen that ability

Comment: From a WebExtension, as you appear to have already found, [native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) is the only way.

Comment: For the downvoter - have you seen the amount of stuff one must do to just run a program? An action which was trivial (as I posted) is now so unbelievably overengineered. I think Firefox has dug its own grave by getting rid of proper full addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation (and as others, like Jaromanda X, wrote) it seems that it's not possible without a lot of boilerplate around the native messaging.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might look at a custom protocols. If the program run is initiated by user, you could just use a link, e.g. "myschema://somearguments" to run the external program. More info there - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol#Firefox_3.5_and_above.